# Moving percentages on Python - Pandas

Tags: python, dataframe

suppose I have the following table (headers are days and 100 are amounts)

What I need is to generate a distribution of [50%, 30% and 20%] of the amounts from the next day.

Any suggestions are welcome.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'0': [100], '1': [100], '2': [100], '3': [100]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df 

    0   1   2   3
0   100 100 100 100

d = {'0': [0,0,0,0], '1': [50,0,0,0], '2': [30,50,0,0], '3': [20,30,50,0], '4': [0,20,30,50],'5': [0,0,20,30],'6': [0,0,0,20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6
0   0   50  30  20  0   0   0
1   0   0   50  30  20  0   0
2   0   0   0   50  30  20  0
3   0   0   0   0   50  30  20
```

Comment: How does this work? Can you give a little explanation?

Comment: The idea is that a loop runs through each of the elements of the first table (that of the amounts of 100) and creates a fall in flows (with the %) for each amount it finds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what I was looking for:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'dia': [1,2,3,4,5], 'monto': [100,100,100,100,100]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

ratios=[0.5,0.3,0.2]

my_new_list = []
for i, monto in enumerate(df['monto']):
    dias=[0]*(i+1)
    montos = [r * monto for r in ratios]
    montos.extend(dias)
    montos.sort(reverse = False) 
    my_new_list.append(montos)


my_new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the float option to run on each line.
 **df["DAY"].astype(float)** 
and then you can do regular math on it.